# Single-column row-set exists in another table or a function returns positive value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following table structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/952e7/1

Now I am looking for a solution for the following problem:
Given an input data-time set (see below). And the SQL statement should return all of business IDs with a **given business name**, where every single date-times of the input set are either present in the `ORDERS` table or an additional function's statement is true (these both conditions are **separately** to be checked for each input date-time).

An example how the input date-time dataset looks like:

`WITH DATES_TO_CHECK(DATETIME) AS(SELECT DATE '2021-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-04-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-05-07' FROM DUAL)`

To be simple, the "additional function" should be a simple random number (if greather than 0.5 than true otherwise false, so the check is `dbms_random.value > 0.5`).

For one given date time it would look like:

```
SELECT BN.NAME, BD.ID 
FROM BUSINESS_DATA BD, BUSINESS_NAME BN 
WHERE BD.NAME_ID=BN.ID AND
BN.NAME='B1' AND
(TO_DATE('2021-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD') IN (SELECT OD.ORDERDATE FROM ORDERS OD WHERE OD.BUSINESS_ID=BD.ID)
 OR dbms_random.value > 0.5)
ORDER BY BD.ID
```

Please help me, how this solution can be applied to the input date-time rowset above AND the specified name.

Comment: `WITH DATES_TO_CHECK(DATETIME) AS('2020-01-01', '2020-03-02' FROM DUAL)` - this is invalid sql statement. Please, provide the structure of *datetime input set*.

Comment: @astentx, thanks. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't any difference with the question you just deleted

This is the list of businesses named B1 and for which the number of order dates that match date input dates is equal to the number of input dates or dbms_random.value > 0.5

see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb1ae3/21)

```
WITH DATES_TO_CHECK(DATETIME) AS(
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-03' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-04-08' fROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-05-07' fROM DUAL
),
businesses_that_match as (
    select
    od.BUSINESS_ID, count(distinct OD.ORDERDATE)
  from DATES_TO_CHECK dtc
    left join ORDERS od on OD.ORDERDATE = dtc.datetime
  group by od.BUSINESS_ID
  having count(distinct OD.ORDERDATE) = (select count(distinct DATETIME) from DATES_TO_CHECK)
)
SELECT
  BN.NAME, BD.ID
FROM BUSINESS_DATA BD
  inner join BUSINESS_NAME BN on BD.NAME_ID=BN.ID
  left join businesses_that_match btm on btm.BUSINESS_ID = bd.id
where bn.name = 'B1'
      AND (btm.BUSINESS_ID is not null
      OR dbms_random.value > 0.5
      )
```

Comment: I did not formed my question well, and therefore it was misunderstanding. 
What I try to achive, let me explain with an example: 

1. Order #1 passes, since all dates from the input set are present there. 
2. Order #2 may pass, because some of the input dates are present AND for the missing dates the random function MAY also pass => but the random number is to be checked for EACH missing separately (not once at the end)! 
3. Order #3 same. As I see, the second subquery "businesses_that_match" should provide the random numbers' passes as "second chance" for each missing dates.